# Can I overvolt a motor when the current stays within the limits?

Tags: motor, dc-motor, computers, fan, electricity

I have a 12V 0.24A computer fan. When I supply it with the 12V, it drains something like 0.17A. Can I increase the voltage until the current reaches 0.24A or will it destroy the motor?

Comment: No. The current is load dependent but the max voltage is still the max voltage. If it breaks or not in real life you have to find out yourself but your interpretation if the nameplate does not work that way.

Comment: Specifically, a DC fan motor is usually brushless, so it incorporates drive electronics, which may fail above max DC volts. So in this case I'd say, not recommended. There are other cases where motors can be run above rated voltage - with care - they simply run faster. They can also wear out faster - especially brushed motors, where you can destroy the brushes. Brushless motors can probably be overvolted if you supply your own drive electronics rated for the higher voltage.  But any such motor, if heavily loaded, will overheat much faster too.

Comment: You can easily increase voltage 10% but bearing wear may be faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A well designed 12V  BLDC fan ought to be able to run 6~16V. This is the absolute max for the Cap voltage if you do not exceed the current spec then conduction losses and self heating will not increase and motor increases efficiency.

- but then bearings wear out faster.

  - It may fail locked rotor test at this 16V voltage with no air flow.
- for ideal cooling, force turbulent flow at max surface velocity over hotspot with vent design, but use duct for laminar flow of heat removal and avoid grid block at blade surface for eddy current noise and flow restriction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've overvolted this motor just for a while at 16V and it drawed exactly 0.24A. The motor didn't smell bad at all and it also did not overheat.

Comment: It would be reasonable to assume fan self cools BLDC switches, which has an air speed vs cooling rate limit . My assumptions are correct.